# pythion script converted to .exe does nothing

Tags: python, exe

So I usually use Pyinstaller to make this conversion, however, in this particular client I do not have this package nor can I install it, so I used cx_Freeze but I don't know much about this package.
my code to do the conversion is the following:

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\WinPython\WinPython-64bit-3.7.2.0\python- 
3.7.2.amd64\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\WinPython\WinPython-64bit-3.7.2.0\python- 
3.7.2.amd64\tcl\tk8.6'

setup(name = "download_ibama" ,
     version = "0.1" ,
     description = "" ,
     executables = [Executable("download_ibama.py")])
```

it converts perfectly but when I try to run the .EXE file it does nothing, not even an error message. I tryied with the raw script and it's still working, how would I come about at least going after what is going wrong here?

Comment: Without the script, ideally in the form of a [MCVE], it's hard to tell. There are rules for how scripts must be configured that are easily broken without consequence when run as raw scripts, but break when converted to `.exe`. First step: Put a `print` (with `flush=True` or printing to `file=sys.stderr`) in the script near the top (and again in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guarded portion), rebuild, run it in a `cmd.exe` window, see if anything shows up.

Comment: the script itself is quite big therefore i thought it would just annoy people, but if it's better to edit and post it I could, only that it has more than 150 lines.

Comment: I'll try what you suggested and see what I get, thanks btw :)

Comment: Part of the goal of making a [MCVE] is to reduce your problem case to something simple that still exhibits the bug; if the problem applies to a huge GUI app, odds are you could copy the Hello World GUI example from the `tkinter` module docs and get a similar problem. And if you don't, you can try to figure out what you're doing differently. Done properly, the process of composing a [MCVE] usually reveals the problem before you even need to ask a question (and if it doesn't, at least you've got something manageable for other folks to help with, which increases the odds you get a good answer).